# TensorFlow batch normalization, dimension error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm tensorflow beginner. I'm just trying to use Batch Normalization for improving MNIST accuracy upto 99.5%. I use CNN. But I've some problems.

```
with tf.name_scope('convolution_pooling_1'):
        phase = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='phase')
        W_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3,1,num_filters1], stddev=0.1), name='conv_1_filter')
        h_conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(
            x_image, W_conv1, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME',
            name='filter-output_1')
        bn1 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(h_conv1, 
                                      center=True, scale=True, 
                                      is_training=phase)

        W_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3,1,num_filters1], stddev=0.1), name='conv_2_filter')
        h_conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(
            bn1, W_conv2, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME',
            name='filter-output_2')
        b_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_filters1]))
        h_conv2_cutoff = tf.nn.relu(h_conv2 + b_conv2, name='conv_2_cutoff')    
        bn2 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(h_conv2_cutoff, 
                                      center=True, scale=True, 
                                      is_training=phase)
```

This is my first part of CNN.
1. I wanna design the model by this way. 
32filters Convolution - Batch Normalization - 32filters Convolution - Batch Normalization

But during the training, i got this error

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 32 and 1 for 'convolution_pooling_1/filter-output_2' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,28,28,32], [3,3,1,32].
```

Result of my Batch Normalization doesn't match the next convolution calc?

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the batch normalization, but the filter shape of your second convolutional layer. You defined it to be **[3,3,1,32]** (see error message), but it needs to be **[3,3,32,32]**.
Just correct the shape for your W_conv2 variable:

```
W_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3,num_filters1,num_filters1], stddev=0.1),name='conv_2_filter')
```

Comment: Oh, I should check the filter shapes. Thank you very much! :-)